# using delay between actions

Tags: python, function, loops, delayed-execution

I was trying to communicate python to an arduino using pyserial library. In the code below i am just showing few functions from where i am trying to switch on or off LED based on value returned by these functions. What i want to do is when python is telling to switch on the LED, i want LED to be switched on for 7 seconds, but during that time if `set_forbidden_list` returns any value, i want the LED to switch off immediately and keep it switched off until `set_forbidden_list` becomes empty. Any help will be heavily appreciated.

```
def openthedoor(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id,set_forbidden_list,set_accepted_list_frozen):
    if(((len(set_accepted_list)) >0) & (set_forbidden_list == set()) & ((set_accepted_list_frozen == None) or ((set_accepted_list_frozen & set_accepted_list)== set_accepted_list))):
        use_door(1)
        delay_for_goodant(1)
        print "open the gate"
    else:
        use_door(0)
        delay_for_goodant(0)
        print "close the gate"
    set_for_comparison = set(set_accepted_list &  set_list_ant_id)
    list_for_comparison = list(set_for_comparison)
    return set_for_comparison,list_for_comparison    

def establishing_connection():
    print ser.read();
    ser.write('1')

last_action = -1

def use_door(activate):
    global last_action
    if(last_action != activate):
        send_data(activate)
    last_action = activate

def send_data(data):
    if (data ==0):
        print "manga"
        return True
    else:
        print "muringa"
        return False

def delay_for_goodant(data):
    print "thenga"
    global ser
    try:
        if (ser == None):
            ser = serial.Serial("COM1",9600,timeout = 0)
            print "reconnect"
            incoming_data = ser.readline()
        else:                           ## for turning off the LED
            ser.write('0')
            time.sleep(0)
            incoming_data2 = ser.readline()
    except IOError:
        ser = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using time.sleep(7) to completely halt the program for 7 seconds what you could do is to sleep for a few milliseconds inside a loop which keeps checking if there is any value in the set_forbidden_list. Also `time.sleep(0)` is as good as not writing it at all.

```
for i in range(700):
   time.sleep(0.01);
   if len(set_forbidden_list)==0:
        #switchon the LED
```

The above loop runs 700 times while each time it wait for 0.01 seconds , which sums up to 7 seconds.

Comment: this also works similar to time.sleep(). The system sleeps for 7 seconds. So in the sleeping time when `set_forbidden_list` returns a value, it wont dim the LED.